Why does Lua handle multiple function return values this way?
I was experimenting with Lua for the first time and I am very confused about a certain aspect of how multiple return values are handled when passed into another function.
Consider the following code:
function foo()
    return 1, 2
end
print(foo())
print(foo(), foo())

When running this, I get the following output
1   2
1   1   2

So it seems that when a parameter evalutes to multiple values, only the first value is actually passed into the function unless that is the last parameter. I later looked into the Lua documentation and it clearly confirms that this is the expected behavior

We get all results only when the call is the last (or the only) expression in a list of expressions.

Source
My question is, why? Is there a reason why the last parameter must be treated differently from all the others? As I'm new to the language, I am interested in understanding the philosophy behind these decisions.
This question was marked as duplicate, but I don't think the linked post is asking the same question at all. This behavior isn't dependent on a variable number of arguments. Consider this code:
function foo(a, b, c)
    return a + b + c
end
function bar()
    return 1, 1
end

foo(bar(), 1) -- throws error for trying to add nil
foo(1, bar()) -- works as expected

I also don't believe this to be an off-topic question because it seems important to know for when I actually end up using functions that return multiple values. Given the example above, for example, what would be better programming practice if I wanted to take the two values of bar and feed them into the first two arguments of foo?

Language design questions are usually off topic for SO - check out this Meta question for a pretty lengthy explanation why.

The real reason can only be given by Lua's developers. Most likely because it makes things a lot easier and the user can still achieve expansion of both lists manually if needed.

I don't think the linked question/answer applies, as it looks quite easy, in case of Lua vm stack, to add ability to handle multiple multiret calls. Also, we have at least one original Lua developer here on SO. Maybe he wanted to reply?
